# How to set a hardware note using the SoftLayer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I use python to set the note on a Hardware_Server via the API?  I've been looking through the available methods in [Hardware_Server](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server), and don't see a method for `setNote`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add notes or edit other SoftLayer_Hardware_Server properties you need to use the method SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::editObject.

Below you can see an example to add notes to the BMS with id 123456.

```
"""
Edit a bare metal server's basic information

This example shows how to edit the property 'notes' for a single bare metal server by
using the editObject() method in the SoftLayer_Hardware_Server API service.
See below for more details.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer


# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The id of the bare metal you wish to edit
hardwareId = 123456

'''
The template object used to edit a SoftLayer_Hardware_Server.
Take account you can edit other properties by using a similar skeleton
'''
templateObject = {
    'notes': 'This is my bare metal server!'
}

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    # Add notes to the Bare Metal server
    result = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server'].editObject(templateObject,
                                                            id=hardwareId)
    print('Bare Metal Server edited')
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to edit the server: %s, %s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server

I hope this help you.

Regards,